# What is a cost-effective sound card for under $75?

Tags: audio, sound-cards

I've been focusing on my computer's video and performance so much that I forgot about audio quality, which is surprising because I'm somewhat of an audiophile. So, I'm in the market for a sound card with at least these specs:

- PCIe x1 interface
- at least 5.1 channels
- 24-bit audio output
- at least 96KHz sample rate
- high SNR (at least 108dB)

Things I don't want at all:

- a sound card in an external enclosure (or one that includes external parts)
- FireWire

Maximum price I'll pay right now is $75. I wish I could bump this up to the hundreds, but, alas, money is tight.

Comment: What does your on-motherboard chip provide? Actually, its model number would be enough. What you request above is satisfied by  a mobo with an ALC889, if I recall correctly. (That's $2 chip or so.)

Comment: @Respawned I want a dedicated sound card regardless of what onboard chipset I have.

Comment: Ok, just be aware that when I bought my last HTPC motherboard (for $50) it came with said chip... which is meeting your specs. It even gets a bit of praise in that direction at http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/high-end-pc-audio,3733-6.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asus Xonar DX 7.1 is [on sale at Newegg](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16829132006) for $75+ $4 shipping - $10MIR = $69.

- PCIe x1 interface? Yes.
- at least 5.1 channels? 7.1
- 24-bit audio output? Yes
- at least 96KHz sample rate? 192KHz
- high SNR (at least 108dB)? claims 116dB

Response: No, I don't have first hand experience with this card, but I do with another Asus (external) sound product, Xonar U7, that's ok. This was the only card that I found meets both your noise level and price requirements. If you relax the noise level a bit, you get much cheaper stuff, for example:

[Creative Sound Blaster Audigy FX 5.1 PCIe Sound Card with 600 ohm Headphone Amp](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=29-102-062)

- PCIe x1 interface? Yes.
- at least 5.1 channels? 5.1
- 24-bit audio output? Yes
- at least 96KHz sample rate? 192KHz
- high SNR (at least 108dB)? claims *106dB*
- $32.99 + free shipping

In case you wonder, the "600 ohm Headphone Amp" means it has a separate, relatively powerful headphone amplifier onboard, which can drive "difficult" (that is high-impedance) headphone like Sennheiser HD600 (which cost about 10x what this card does, so it's a bit questionable that you'd want this cheap card for those). This feature doesn't affect/matter for the 5.1 speakers output.

And since you're probably going to ask... no I don't first-hand experience with this card either. The last Creative (proper) card I had was an Audigy 2 (PCI); quality was as advertised. I also have an E-MU 1212M, which is their professional brand basically; outside your price range by a factor of at least 2 and not 5.1 etc.